# Visualizing a complex valued function of one real parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, visualization

I'm looking for a way to capture/graph or visualize it in my head, but I can't find how..

a 2-dimensional path won't do, because it doesn't reveal the rate-of-change..
2 1-dimensional graphs on top of each other doesn't help much either..
3-dimensional space with 2-dimensional slices for values of the parameter is the best I could come up with..

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a certain complex valued function in the mind?

Comment: More like any smooth function.. $e^{ix}$ could help though

Comment: Whether practical or not, you can visualize plotting the magnitude z=|f(x+iy)| as a 3d graph, and overlaying small pointing arrows to indicate complex angular component. A 'pole' really looks like a pole for that graph, and winding number can be seen by how many times the arrows spin completely around as you follow a path. Branch cuts show discontinuity in arrow pointing directions, etc.. It cleans up the plot of the exponential very nicely.

Comment: @T.A.E. I'm not sure I fully understand what you meant.. Can you please elaborate a bit more? This could very much be an answer not just a comment btw.. :)

Comment: @Dror: Have you tried using Mathematica, Maple or any other Maths software?

Comment: @B.S. I have used Mathematica, but not for this purpose yet.. Perhaps I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Dror: I made a plot of `exp(I*x), x = -Pi .. Pi` in Maple. Is it satisfying? Or `exp(z*I), z=-I..I` would be better?

Comment: @B.S. Are you being sarcastic..?

Comment: @Dror: Why do u think like that? :-)

Comment: @B.S. Just a hunch.. In any case I'm not free to plot myself because I'm at work.. If you'd like to show me one of your plots I'd be glad..

Comment: @Dror: An alternative to trying to superimpose planar arrows would to be use color to encode the argument between 0 and 2 pi. Color is a great tool for helping you see the variation of the argument. That's probably what one person was doing in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a picture that represents the complete information inherent in a function
$$f:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb C},\qquad t\mapsto z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$$
you need three real dimensions, because informationwise a function is equivalent to its graph, which is a subset of domain$\times$range, and this cartesian product has real dimension $3$ in your case.

When the given function $f$ describes a phenomenon in time you should draw the $t$-axis more or less horizontally extending to the right, the $x$-axis would have to go to the rear, and the $y$-axis points  vertically upwards. The "worldline" of your particle moving around in ${\mathbb C}$ then looks as follows:

[image]

If you are much more interested in the geometry of the $2$D-curve obtained by projection to ${\mathbb C}$, and want to see self-intersections, etc., instead of the exact time-table, you'd rather lie ${\mathbb C}$ horizontally by drawing the $x$-axis going to the right and the $y$-axis going to the rear; finally the $t$-axis goes vertically upwards. This would give rise to a picture of the following kind:

[image]

Comment: What a wonderful answer! I'd double up-vote if I could.

Answer (score 3):

```
[> with(plots):
  f := z-> exp(I*z):
  complexplot3d(f, -2-2*I .. 2+2*I);
```

[image]

Or

```
[> complexplot(exp(I*x), x = -Pi .. Pi);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm not sure how to interpret the color coding.. and maybe perhaps a better plot replacing the later will simply be a 3-dimensional helix..?

Comment: @Dror: Maple does the colors by itself. I just insert the function you intended. As you wanted in the title, the second one is the complex valued function defined on reals.